# how to make a regex to match dates, except one in particular

Tags: java, regex, selenium, junit4

I'm doing tests with selenium. I filtered the record for a date (example: 10/03/2013) there should be records of other dates.

How can I validate this in Selenium?
I think that a regular expression can be useful.

Ps: date in dd/MM/YYYY format

Edit: source: http://pastebin.com/F16rSHwE

Comment: please show us some code.

Comment: @Woot4Moo Really did not think it needed to be just a regex, but I edited the post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use zero-width negative lookahead assertions.

```
(?!<YOUR-EXCLUDED-DATE-PATTERN>)<GENERIC-DATE-PATTERN>
```

Answer (score 0):

this regex should do the trick:

```
^(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])//(0[1-9]|1[012])//(19|20)\d\d
```

**Please note**

- I am always bad with escaping long expressions, so please doublecheck me please :)
- This will match *any* date in dd/MMM/YYYY format, so if you want to exclude one, some other logic will be needed
- Right now, my proxy is refusing connection to pastebin, so I cannot have peek to your code to help more (simple copypaste to question should be better option)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Unfortunately it is not useful. I can match a date. The difficulty is to exclude one in particular.